# cauchy estimates for derivatives

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D$ be the unit disc centered at the origin and f olomorphic in the disc. Show that

$2|f'(0)|\leq sup_ {z,w\in D}|f(z)-f(w)|$

Furthermore, we have equality if and only if f is linear.

I only know Cauchy's estimation for derivatives:

$f^{(n)}(0)\leq \frac{n!}{r^n}Max_{|z|=r} |f|$ for $0<r<1$

but i've no idea how to apply this to this case.

Comment: The Cauchy estimates are kind of useless here.  Try starting from the definition of the complex derivative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cauchy's derivative-integral formula:

$$f'(0) = \frac{1}{2\pi \imath} \int_{|\xi|=r} \frac{f(\xi)}{\xi^2} \, d\xi$$

where $0<r<1$. Thus

$$2f'(0)= \frac{1}{2\pi \imath} \int_{|\xi|=r} \frac{f(\xi)-f(-\xi)}{\xi^2} \, d\xi \\
\Rightarrow 2|f'(0)| \leq \frac{1}{2\pi \imath} \cdot \frac{2\pi r}{r^2} \cdot \sup\{|f(\xi)-f(-\xi)|; |\xi|=r\} \\ \leq \frac{1}{r} \cdot \sup\{|f(z)-f(w)|; z,w \in D\}$$

Now let $r \to 1$...

Clearly the equality holds if $f$ is linear. On the other hand: Since $f(z) = \sum_{n \geq 0} a_n \cdot z^n$ we have

$$\sup_{w,z \in D} |f(z)-f(w)| = \sup_{w,z \in D} \left| f'(0) \cdot (z-w)+\sum_{n \geq 2} a_n \cdot (z^n-w^n) \right| \stackrel{!}{=} 2|f'(0)|$$ and this can only hold if $a_n =0$ for all $n \geq 2$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the last part? Why can equality hold only if $a_n = 0$ for all $n \ge 2$? Am I overlooking something simple?

Comment: @MartinR WLOG $f'(0)=0$ (otherwise consider $\tilde{f}(z):=f(z)-f'(0) z$). The identity from the last display then reads $$\sup_{z,w \in D} \left| \sum_{n \geq 2} a_n(z^n-w^n) \right|=0,$$ i.e. $$\sum_{n \geq 2} a_n (z^n-w^n)=0, \qquad z,w \in D.$$ Choose $w=0$, then $$\sum_{n \geq 2} a_n z^n =0.$$ This entails $a_n=0$ for $n \geq 2$ (e.g. by differentiating both sides with respect to $z$)

Comment: I am not yet convinced about the “WLOG”. You have $\tilde f'(0) = 0$, but how do you get $\sup_{z, w} |\tilde f(z) - \tilde f(w)| = 2|\tilde f'(0)|$?